# How can we persist ProductDetails in Google Play Billing Library 5 and 6 to disk?

Tags: java, android, android-billing, play-billing-library

In billing library version 4, we can use `querySkuDetailsAsync` to retrieve `SkuDetails`

```
String sku = skuDetails.getSku();

final Map<String, String> skuToOriginalJsons = new HashMap<>();

skuToOriginalJsons.put(sku, skuDetails.getOriginalJson());

//
// We can persist skuToOriginalJsons to disk
//

//
// We can restore SkuDetails from disk.
//
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : skuToOriginalJsons.entrySet()) {
    try {
        SkuDetails skuDetails = new SkuDetails(entry.getValue());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    }
}
```

An advantage of using `SkuDetails` is that, even `querySkuDetailsAsync` is failing, we still able to retrieve `SkuDetails` from disk.

However, in billing library 5 and 6, using `queryProductDetailsAsync` to retrieve `ProductDetails` is recommended.

`ProductDetails` doesn't provide `getOriginalJson()`, and do not have ability to construct from JSON.

Is that is so, is there any reliable strategy for us to write and restore `ProductDetails` from disk, in case `queryProductDetailsAsync` is failing?

Answer (score 1):

Persisting `ProductDetails` to disk is not reliable as `offerToken`, which is used to purchase subscriptions starting from Billing Library 5, may expire quite frequently